# Error Report from a terminated process (expected to be normal)

Tags: erlang, eunit

I have a test module that tests my `Table` module.
My `Table` module, when it terminates, calls this:

```
terminate(_, State = {Board, Status, Players}) ->
  gen_server:stop(Board),
  ...stopping other processes,
  io:format("Table Terminating.~p~n", [State]),
  ok.
```

This is the only part of my code that would stop a `Board` process.

After running my tests, I will get this after about a minute:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 21-Jul-2017::22:28:40 ===
** Generic server <0.92.0> terminating
** Last message in was []
** When Server state == [[{spawn,x,none},
                          {recent,x,none},
                          {empty,null,none},
                          {empty,null,none},
                          {empty,null,none}],
                         [{empty,null,none},
                          {empty,null,none},
                          {empty,null,none},
                          {ridge,null,none},
                          {empty,null,none}],
                         [{empty,null,none},
                          {empty,null,none},
                          {ridge,null,none},
                          {empty,null,none},
                          {empty,null,none}],
                         [{empty,null,none},
                          {ridge,null,none},
                          {empty,null,none},
                          {empty,null,none},
                          {empty,null,none}],
                         [{empty,null,none},
                          {empty,null,none},
                          {empty,null,none},
                          {empty,null,none},
                          {spawn,o,none}]]
** Reason for termination ==
** {terminated,[{io,format,
                    [<0.90.0>,"Board.~p~n",
                     [[[{spawn,x,none},
                        {recent,x,none},
                        {empty,null,none},
                        {empty,null,none},
                        {empty,null,none}],
                       [{empty,null,none},
                        {empty,null,none},
                        {empty,null,none},
                        {ridge,null,none},
                        {empty,null,none}],
                       [{empty,null,none},
                        {empty,null,none},
                        {ridge,null,none},
                        {empty,null,none},
                        {empty,null,none}],
                       [{empty,null,none},
                        {ridge,null,none},
                        {empty,null,none},
                        {empty,null,none},
                        {empty,null,none}],
                       [{empty,null,none},
                        {empty,null,none},
                        {empty,null,none},
                        {empty,null,none},
                        {spawn,o,none}]]]],
                    []},
                {board,terminate,2,[{file,"board.erl"},{line,319}]},
                {gen_server,try_terminate,3,
                            [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,629}]},
                {gen_server,terminate,7,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,795}]},
                {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                          [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]
```

which looks like the `Board` module terminated improperly. The `Board`'s terminate is such:

```
terminate(normal, State) ->
    io:format("Board.~p~n", [State]),
    ok.
```

I tried to reproduce this in a standalone module, `b`:

```
-module(b).
-compile(export_all).

init([]) -> {ok, {1, 2}}.

terminate(_, State) ->
  io:format("Table Terminating.~p~n", [State]),
  ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}. 

handle_cast(_, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(Msg, State) ->
  io:format("Unexpected message: ~p~n",[Msg]),
  {noreply, State}.

go() ->
  gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [], []).
```

Unsuccessfully:

`4> {ok, B} = b:go().
{ok,<0.74.0>}
5> gen_server:stop(B).
Table Terminating.{1,2}`

What I am wondering is, what kind of code should I look for that would cause my Board to get the `** Reason for termination ==
** {terminated` reason for stopping?

Full source is here: git@github.com:QuantumProductions/tunnel.git

Edit: Board includes this

```
handle_call(stop, _From, State) ->
    {stop, normal, shutdown_ok, State};
handle_call(_, _, Board) ->
  {reply, {error, unrecognized, Board}, Board}.
```

EDIT: My best guess is `eunit` is automatically terminated processes created within its tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why `borad` last message is `[]`?  According to the code you used `gen_server:stop/1` which calls `gen:stop/1` which calls `gen:stop/3` which calls [`proc_lib:stop/3`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/gen.erl#L243) which finally calls [`sys:terminate/3`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/proc_lib.erl#L886). When you call `sys:terminate/3` for a gen_server, sys calls [`gen_server:system_terminate/4`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-19.3.6/lib/stdlib/src/gen_server.erl#L745) and it calls [`gen_server:terminate/6`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-19.3.6/lib/stdlib/src/gen_server.erl#L790) with `[]` as last message !

why `borad` terminated with reason `{terminated, ...}`?  According to the `io` code, `io:format/2` finally calls [`io:execute_request/2`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/io.erl#L568) and you got [`this`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/io.erl#L586) because io process terminated and in [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/io.erl#L67) it becomes `{terminated, ...}`.

Comment: I guess that you lost io process just in Eunit tests and i recommend to use standard sys debugging instead io:format. http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html#debug

Comment: So is Eunit telling the process to terminate then? When you say "lost process" - you mean Eunit killed it?

Comment: I guess that Eunit kills io process(es), i have not time to read its code, but it kills io processes and you can not call io:format successfully